# Why can't I use 'name' as a variable/object name?

Tags: javascript

When declaring an object like this:

```
var name= {
    firsName:"nur",
    lastName:"jaman",
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firsName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
console.log(name.fullName());
```

it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: name.fullName is not a function
```

However, using any other variable name (e.g. `var hello = ...`) works just fine. Why?

Comment: why downvote? he is right

Comment: @Luthando Right about what?

Comment: there is a build in property called name for window object. all your global names point to window and it is a string.  console.log(window.name) you ll see it s aempty string and you cannot override it

Comment: @jaman If you're executing the code in browser console, remove `<script>` tags

Comment: it gives this error `Uncaught TypeError: name.fullName is not a function`

Comment: @Deepak Now that the question makes sense, this would be a great answer.

Comment: oh now i see you decided to remove your downvotes....try the provided code before downvote

Comment: @Luthando 1) For a short period the code in the question actually *did* work just fine. 2) If you say it throws an error, **always cite the error message**. It could be a million different things. For that alone downvotes are justified.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot It was down-voted because: No error message was provided *"It doesn't work"* is not a good problem statement. The user had the variable `var hello = { ... }` (when I was viewing it), which works fine and has no problems. But since those problems were fixed, that's why we removed them. Not because we didn't read the question properly.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot absolutely a valid question when you write a lot of vanilla javascript!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because [`name` is a existing property on `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), that behaves a little different from normal variables.

You can't replace this property, you can only assign string values to it. When assigning other types to the name property, it gets cast to string:

```
name = false;
var name = false;
window.name = false;
```

These lines will all result in `window` having a property `name` that contains `"false"`.

In a similar fashion, objects and functions saved to the `name` variable will be cast to string:

```
var name = function(){};  // "function (){}"
var name = { a: [1, 2] }; // "[object Object]"
```

---

If you want to use a variable named "name", you'll have to enclose it in a scope:

```js
// In the global namespace, this will alert `"[object Object]"`
var name = { a: 1};
alert('Global `name`: \n' +
      JSON.stringify(name));

// In it's own namespace, this will alert `{"a":1}`.
(function(){
  var name = { a: 1};
  alert('Namespaced `name`: \n' +
        JSON.stringify(name));
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any enclosing scope, `var name` is [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), which is a native property which cannot be replaced or overridden. You can assign a *string* to it, but even then it keeps being an object with special properties:

```
> name
< "[object Object]"
> name.anchor
< function anchor() {
    [native code]
}
> name = null
> name
< "null"
> typeof name
< "string"
> name.anchor
< function anchor() {
    [native code]
}
```

Note that the whole thing works just fine when scoped:

```
function () {
    var name = { .. };
    console.log(name.fullName()); 
}()
```