# Why does the variable type always "string" if it's not initialized by var, let or const or if it's still assigned to a number type?

Tags: javascript

I was working with the variables and datatypes and found that I can also define variables without initializing it with var, let or const. But when I defined a variable without var, let or const it becomes the type of "string" always. If I assigned my variable with number then too its type becomes string. If I add two numbers let's say 10 and 20, it gets add and results 30 but the type still shows its a string. So if anyone could explain me why is it always showing string.

```js
car = "Mercedes";
console.log(car); // outputs Mercedes
console.log(typeof car); // outputs string

car = 123;
console.log(car); // outputs 123
console.log(typeof car); // outputs string

car = 10 + 20;
console.log(car); // outputs 30
console.log(typeof car); // outputs string
```

Comment: Works as expected here. I can think of situations in which this odd behavior *could* occur, but they're quite strange, can you edit the question into a [MCVE]?

Comment: In your real code, are you really using the variable name `car`, or was it perhaps `name` or `status` or something like that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am using variable named `car` from the very start. Assume that the above code is the only code I have in my JavaScript file.

Comment: The problem you describe does not occur given the exact code in the question. Run the snippet to see for yourself.

Comment: Please share the correct demo. The output here is not same as you have commented here.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried it in VSCode and it outputs string when I run that into dev-tools (Console). I don't know why it is having number type when I run here!?

Comment: I can't reproduce in VSCode's Node https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebss.png

Comment: @JainamParikh Running the code above in Chrome's console, Firefox, or the Nodejs REPL, or in Stackoverflow's "Run Code Snippet" provides the expected response (string, number, number). Perhaps this is a bug specific to your runtime, in which case please provide the setup and code required to reproduce.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You were right. I used `name` as a variable and that is why it shows string.

Comment: Then why did you say `I am using variable named car from the very start` when I specifically asked if you were using `name`??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369779/why-cant-i-use-name-as-a-variable-object-name

Comment: @CertainPerformance That was my mistake. I am new to this Stack Overflow Question part and I somehow messed it up. Sorry for your loss.

Comment: For future reference, please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Zuckerberg Will surely do. Sorry for messing up.

Comment: @Zuckerberg Yup. That answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without `var`, `let`, or `const`, a variable is global, i.e. a property on the global object. In a browser, it is the `window` object. Setting `car=123` is the same as setting `window.car=123`, and will produce a value of type `number`.

Some window properties are special though. E.g. setting `name=123` or `window.name = 123` actually invokes a setter, and the property `name` will always have type `string`.

Any property can be made special in this way. E.g. the following definition will make your example work as you described:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'car', { 
  set: function(x) { this._car = String(x); },
  get: function() { return this._car; } 
});
```

Comment: But OP says: *I am using variable named car from the very start*, and `car` is not one of those special global properties

Comment: I typed this before seeing that comment. But a property with custom getter/setter still a likely explanation of what OP is seeing. Updating to clarify.

Comment: @Snow Yeah, I got it. I used `name` as a variable name and it only shows string. If I use `car` then it follows the rule. Thank You.